# Read int numbers from cin until ESC is pressed C++

Tags: c++, escaping, cin

I am interested to find a solution for the following problem:

I have to read int numbers form CIN until the user presses ESC and compute the average of the positive and even integers.

My problem is i am not quite sure how correctly write the stopping condition.

Here's what i've tried so far(not working properly)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int c, sum=0, i=0;
cout<<"Insert characters: ";
while(cin>>c)
{
    i++;
    if((int)c>=0&&(int)c%2==0){
        sum+=(int)c;
    }
}
cout<<"Average: "<<(float)sum/i<<endl;
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: I dont know how to check for the escape key, but you need to move `i++` inside the `if()` condition, otherwise you're counting all even and odd integers.

Comment: You are reading numbers, but ESC is not a number, but a control code. I think it won't even be passed through the >> operator. You have to use some sort of low level console reading function to access special keypresses.

Comment: Brady that's right about the i++, but i am still stuck on the exit condition...

Comment: Also, what if someone presses a letter instead of a number? Why does the exit condition have to be ESC? Why not make it a 'q' or something just as simple?

Comment: this is the requirement....:) it would have been to easy to put the stopping condition on a simple char...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The escape character is neither a digit nor a space. Thus, if the program gets passed the character in the stream, you can just read integers and the stream will automatically fail when an espace characters is entered (just concentrating on the input aspect of the question):

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    int c = 0;
    while (std::cin >> c) {
        std::cout << "c=" << c << '\n';
    }
}
```

Whether the escape characters is forwarded to the stream by the operating system is, however, a different question. For example, on UNIXes the escape character will be forwarded but only when the input is given to the program which, by default, is when a line is entered. If the program shouldn't wait for the return key, the operating system needs to get told to not wait for the return key.

The question seems to be for Windows but I don't know enough about Windows to determine how to change the terminal settings there (see below for something which may still work, though). On UNIXes, you'd clear the `ICANON` flag in the terminal settings using `tcgetattr()` and `tcsetattr()`. For example, you could use this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <termios.h>

int main()
{
    termios values;
    tcgetattr(0, &values);
    values.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &values);

    int c = 0;
    while (std::cin >> c) {
        std::cout << "c=" << c << '\n';
    }
}
```

I think there is `getch()` on Windows which get you one character without waiting. This, hopefully, also includes the escape character. If that's the case you could just create a simple stream buffer around `getch()` and use that instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <streambuf>
#include <whatever-declares-getch>

struct getchbuf
    : std::streambuf {
    static int const end = <getch()-error-value-goes-here>;
    char buffer;
    int underflow() {
        int result(traits_type::eof());
        if (this->gptr() == this->egptr() && (result = getch()) != end) {
            buffer = traits_type::to_char_type(result);
            this->setg(&buffer, &buffer, &buffer + 1);
        }
        return result;
    }
};

int main()
{
    getchbuf sbuf;
    std::istream in(&sbuf);

    int c = 0;
    while (in >> c) {
        std::cout << "c=" << c << '\n';
    }
}
```

You need to patch up the above code to include whatever declares `getch()` (I think it is `<conio.h>` but I don't know) and to specify `getch()`'s error indicator.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
while((ch = cin.get()) != 27)
{
  i++;
  if((int)ch>=0&&(int)ch%2==0
  {
    sum+=(int)ch;
  }
}
```

This should loop until the `esc` key is pressed

Comment: not working unfortunatelly... the console is stuck with reading, it doesn't stop...

Comment: @AdrianOlar do you mean that the `while` condition is never false?

Comment: This will only work if the user enters in the character whose ASCII value is 27.

Comment: @0x499602D2 and the ASCII value of the `esc` key is 27 http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/ascii.html

Comment: For this to work, one needs the disable the line buffering on cin.

Comment: yes, the while condition is never false. At least this is what i can observe from the output in my console...

Comment: @Pat How does one do that?

Comment: @0x499602D2: that depends on the platform. On a posix-system, you'll need the termios functions (see man pages). On windows, I'm not sure, but you'll probably be better off using the winapi console functions directly.

Comment: i tested your code and this just clears the line contents when i press the ESC button and this never stops listening for input...